# discord.py - How can I make an argument to send certain things?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using the [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to make a discord bot that is like a digital test paper. But then I need to add an argument (or the subject) to make a bot send certain test paper for that subject like `q!testpaper english` will send the English test paper.

This is my code as of now and it's in a [`Cog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog):

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):

    @commands.command()
    async def testpaper(self, ctx):
        testpaper = open("./testpaper.txt", "r").read()
        await ctx.send(f'Good luck taking the test!')
        await ctx.author.send(testpaper)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get other arguments, you can just pass them in the function call. Use a keyword-only notation to match the whole string that was passed after the function call (learn more [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments)).

You also forgot to close the file `"./testpaper.txt"` after opening it. That's why the best way to open a file in Python is by using the [`with open(...) as ...`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) syntax.

I suggest using a [`JSON`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) file to store your tests. Here is an example:

**testpaper.json**

```
{
    "english": "PUT TESTPAPER HERE",
    "math": "PUT OTHER TESTPAPER HERE",
    ...
}
```

Then you access a specific testpaper:

```py
import discord, json
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):

    @commands.command()
    async def testpaper(self, ctx, *, subject=None):
        if not subject:
            await ctx.send("Error: please input subject!")
            return

        subject = subject.lower() # Lower-case only
        with open("./testpaper.json") as f:
            content = json.load(f)

        try:
            paper = content[subject]
        except KeyError:
            await ctx.send("No paper named " + subject)
            return
        await ctx.send(f"Good luck taking the test!")
        await ctx.author.send(paper)
```

Comment: Using JSON makes it hard, most especially when it has over 50 question and it has multiple choice. I have took some reference from your code and modified a bit to read TXT file because it's easier to manage and easy to understand when I hand out my bot to "others".